# Restangular - Get object w/id, edit object, update object

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, put, restangular

I can't seem to figure this out -

I want to do something like:

```
content = Restangular.one('contents', 2).get()
content.name = "Chunky Bacon"
content.put()
```

But this doesn't work - `content` doesn't have a `put` function, and interestingly, it doesn't have a `name`, either (is that because it's a "promise"?)

Now, the Restangular docs do describe updating an object, but you get that object as part of a collection:

```
content_id2 = Restangular.all("contents").getList()[2]
content_id2.name = "Chunky Bacon"
content_id2.put()
```

And this works. But! Not only have I fetched the entire list, I can't figure out how to easily get my content by it's ID; something like `Restangular.all("contents").getList().find(2)`

`customPUT(..)` seems like the next best bet:

```
Restangular.one("contents", 2).customPUT("", {"content" : {"name" : "Chunky Bacon"} } )
```

Only when the Rails server receives it, `params["content"] == {id: 2}` - it seems like something on the client side is stomping that value. (Again, note, no `name` field). Now, I can work around it simply by doing something like:

```
Restangular.one("contents", 2).customPUT("", {"content_data" : {"name" : "Chunky Bacon"} )
```

but it really seems like I'm just missing how you're supposed to do this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Alright, found it, thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254151/how-to-return-edit-rest-resource-with-angularjs-restangular):

```
#In the beginning:
Restangular.one("content", 2).get().then(function(c){
  $scope.content = c
})

#Elsewhere:
$scope.content.name = "Chunky Bacon"

#Finally:
$scope.content.put()
```

Comment: i've done the same and i get still the error "Object not found" when i call the function 'put'.

Comment: That is because Restangular promises and the way values are used directly in templates changed: https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#element-methods