# Null check on returned JSON value in Angular/Restangular not working

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, restangular

I have the following string being returned from a rest service call:

```
            {"fooName":""}
```

In an angular controller, I have:

```
var aFoo= Restangular.one(theRoute).get()
```

I thought this would resolve to true, but it is false:

```
aFoo.fooName.length === 0
```

When I log the following, I get 0:

```
aFoo.fooName.length
```

My ultimate goal is to just check if there is a fooName or not, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17286497/2055998).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use `typeof`: if it is undefined, you have an empty `JSON` Object.
Like so:

```
if (typeof(aFoo.fooName) != "undefined"){
    //something is here
```

More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)