# Put Object in Restangular

Tags: angularjs, rest, angularjs-scope, restangular

You see below my code to change a record from my db using restangular.

```
Restangular.one("/mywebsite/bin/server.fcgi/REST/players", "70").get().then(function(c){
          $scope.content = c;
        })

        $scope.content.Name= "Asqan";

        $scope.content.put();
```

when i try to put as the last line of my code, it gives the error:

```
PUT http://localhost/mywebsite/bin/server.fcgi/REST/players 404 (Object not found)
```

ps: no other issue with adding or getting.

Comment: Your `.get` function is asynchronous, so when it reaches the `$scope.content` it is possibly null/undefined

Comment: yep. this time the error: "unknown property: id". Is this because that property is in my db defined as "ID"? If so, how should i change this?

Comment: Yeah the parameters offcourse should match, otherwise the property won't exist

Comment: thus, what should i do concretely?

Comment: use the properties that you have, so if it is `ID`, then use `ID`

Comment: i'll ask it in another way: in order to change 'id' to "ID" in my restangular query, what should i do precisely?

Comment: I think what you mean is to use `Restangular.one("theurl", { ID: 70 }).get()`

Comment: Errors: (1) TypeError: $scope.content.put is not a function (2) GET http://mywebsite/webevents/bin/server.fcgi/REST/players/%5Bobject%20Object%5D 404 (Object not found)

Answer (score 0):

you should do it in the then function,

```
Restangular.one("/mywebsite/bin/server.fcgi/REST/players", "70").get().then(function(c){

      $scope.content = c;
      $scope.content.Name= "Asqan";
      $scope.content.put();
})
```

Comment: Result is the same. It was my first implementation. I tried that later in this way because i've seen that is served in similar questions as a solution